# How to I extract specific value from JSON API in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a block of code in the controller which can make API requests and retrieve responses. So far, I only know how to print the response with the code below.

```
dd($result["paymentMethods"][0]["brands"]);
```

And this is the result

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => "visa"
  1 => "mc"
  2 => "amex"
  3 => "diners"
  4 => "discover"
  5 => "maestro"
]
```

May I know how do I display this result in view?

Comment: The "usual" way to pass data: [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the result to `view()` function and in your blade show it.

In your controller:

```
$specific_result = $result["paymentMethods"][0]["brands"];

return view('your_view_name', compact('specific_result'));
```

In your blade file:

```
<ul>
@foreach($specific_result as $item)
    <li>{{ $item }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send data to view for that like this...

```
  return response()->view('view_name', $result);
```

and then on view you can fetch to show data like you want eg.

```
 <h1>{{$result["paymentMethods"][0]["brands"]}}</h1>
```

It a reference code might change for you.

Comment: Missing `{{ ... }}` in blade

Comment: @brombeer my bad, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the records from your controller to view:

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class YourController extends Controller {
    public function YourFunction() {
        $results = $result["paymentMethods"][0]["brands"];
        return view('YourViewName', compact('results'));
    }
}
```

Then use `foreach` to print all your data.
**Your View**

```
@if($results)
    @foreach($results AS $result)
        {{ $result }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```